# Optimize or propose c++, c# code using omp to find all similar k motifs

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, openmp

Given A positive integer `k (k≤50)`, a DNA string s of length at most `5,000` representing a motif, and a DNA string t of length at most `50,000` representing a genome.

The problem consists on returning all substrings `t′` of t such that the edit distance `d_E(s,t′)`

> The edit distance between two strings is the minimum number of elementary
>   operations (insertions, deletions, and substitutions) to transform one
>   string into the other, for instamce `s = 'TGCATAT'` and `t' = 'ATCCGAT'` [image]
>   [here is a c++ implementation by](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/edit-distance-between-two-strings) user1131146 account aban 
>   Maybe it would be better to use that??

is less than or equal to `k`. Each substring should be encoded by a pair containing its location in `t` followed by its length.

for instance

```
2
ACGTAG
ACGGATCGGCATCGT
```

should output

```
1 4
1 5
1 6
```

For this example `k=2` results mean:
For indices `1 to 4`, `d_E(s,t′)=2` (ADD `T` THEN one `A` BEFORE LAST `t's G`)

```
s  = ACGTAG
t' = ACGG
```

For indices `1 to 5` `d_E(s,t′)=2` (ADD `G` to end of `t'` THEN replace `t's G` at index 4 by `T`)

```
s  = ACGTAG
t' = ACGGA
```

For indices `1 to 6` `d_E(s,t′)=2` (REPLACE LAST `t's T` BY `G`THEN replace `t's G` at index 4 by `T`)

```
s  = ACGTAG
t' = ACGGAT
```

Having the solution to get `all substrings of a genome that are within a certain fixed distance of the desired motif`,What would be the best way to parallelize a solution using omp. As the longer the strings become program takes too much time.

I have tested using omp `#pragma omp parallel for` then using a `lock` in the write to file section, and also `#pragma omp critical` However I do not know if I am paralelizing it correctly.

```
void alignment(vector<vi>&a, string &x, string y, int k){
    string tx,ty;
    int i,j;
    int ylen=a[0].size();
    for(i=1;i<a.size();i++){
        for(j=max(1,i-k);j<=min(ylen,i+k);j++){ 
            a[i][j] = max(x[i-1] == y[j-1]?a[i-1][j-1] : (a[i-1][j-1]-1), max(a[i-1][j]-1,a[i][j-1]-1));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int k = 23;
    string s = "AATTAGCTAAGGTGTACGATGTCCCATTGTGTAAGATTAGGAACTCCATTTAGGTTACCTCCGTCTTAAGTGATGGACCGTGGGTAGCTGCGTCCGATGGACTCATGCAGCGCCCGGATACCTGCAGTATTTATTATATAGGTCTGCGCACCAAACGATTTCTTTCGTGGTCGGGATTCCGGGGTCCTCCGCTATTCAGAGAGCTAAATA";
    string t = "ACAATGCAGCAATCCAGCGCCGGAATTTAAGAATAGGTCAGTTTGTAAGGCACTGTTCCCGTTATTCGTAATGCAGTATTAACGTTAATGCTCGAGACCATATTGGACGTCAGTATGCAGACCTGTGCTAGGGTGGTCTATTTCAAGATCACCGAGCTAGGCGCGTGAGCTAACAGGCCGTAATGGTGGCGCCCGCTCCCATAATCACTTCACGAAGCATTAGGTAGACTACCATTTAGGAAGCCCTCTCGCCCGCGTACTGGTTACAGCCCACTACAATGGATACTCCTTACTTCGGTGCAGGCAAGACTTCTACAAAGAAGCGTCCAAGAAGTTGTCGTAGCTCGTTCTTACCCCACCTGTATAAAATTGATCCAGTCGTACATATGACGATGCTGAGCCTCGGACTGGTAAATACAAGTCAAAGGACCAACCCATTACAGTATGAACTACCGGTGG";
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    std::ofstream out("output.txt");
    ifstream someStream( "data.txt" );
    string line;
    getline( someStream, line );    int k = atoi(line.c_str() );
    getline( someStream, line );    string s =line;
    getline( someStream, line );    string t= line;
    int slen=s.length(), tlen=t.length();
    vector<vi>a( slen+1, vi(slen+k+1)); 
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<a.size();i++)
        fill(a[i].begin(),a[i].end(),-999),a[i][0]=a[i-1][0]-1;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    {
        for(j=1;j<a[0].size();j++)
        {
            a[0][j]=a[0][j-1]-1;
        }
    }
    //cout << "init";
    time_t endINIT = time(NULL);
    cout<<"Execution Init Time: "<< (double)(endINIT-start)<<" Seconds"<<std::endl;
    //omp_lock_t writelock;
    //omp_init_lock(&writelock);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    {
    for(i=0;i<=tlen-slen+k;i++)
    {
        alignment(a,s,t.substr(i,slen+k),k); 
        for(j=max(0,slen-k);j<=min(slen+k,tlen-i);j++)
        {
            if(a[slen][j]>=-k)
            {

                //omp_set_lock(&writelock);    
                //cout<<(i+1)<<' '<<j<<endl;
                #pragma omp critical 
                {
                    out <<(i+1)<<' '<<j<<endl;
                }
                //omp_unset_lock(&writelock);
            }
        }
    }
    }
    //omp_destroy_lock(&writelock);
    time_t end = time(NULL);
    cout<<"Execution Time: "<< (double)(end-start)<<" Seconds"<<std::endl;  
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I have not been able to complete this or optimize it. Is there a better way?

Comment: it's not a good idea to do file io in the inner loop

Comment: You can't parallelize `a[0][j]=a[0][j-1]-1` the way you have done it. If I understand it correctly you can rewrite it as `a[0][j] = a[0][0]-j` which will parallelize fine. For example for `a[] = {9,3,4,5}` before after the loop it's `{9,8,7,6}`.

Comment: Your code has other problems as well. In your function `alignment` you write to `a` which is shared by each thread.  This is going to cause a race condition. Not only that but how you write to it has dependencies on previous iterations on `i` and `j`. You need to remove the dependencies or maybe use something like a prefix sum if possible.

Comment: So what would be a better aproach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to your post, in order to parallelize calls to `alignment`, each thread needs to have its own copy of `a`.  You can do this with the `firstprivate` OpenMP clause:

```
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(a)
```

In `alignment` itself you repeat calculations in your loops that the optimizer might not be eliminating.  The calls to `a.size` and using `min` in the conditions of your loops could be computed once and stored in a local variable.  Constantly calculating `a[i]` and `a[i-1]` can also be lifted out of the inner loop.

```
int asize = int(a.size());
for(i = 1; i < asize; i++) {
    int jend = min(ylen, i + k);
    vi &cura = a[i];
    vi &preva = a[i-1];
    for(j = max(1, i - k);j <= jend; j++)
        cura[j] = max(x[i-1] == y[j-1]?preva[j-1] : (preva[j-1]-1), max(preva[j]-1,cura[j-1]-1));
}
```

The Windows headers define `max` and `min` macros.  If you're using those (and not the inline functions in the STL) that could also repeat code unnecessarily.

Another bottleneck could be the output of matches, depending on how frequently a match is found.  One way to improve this is to store the `i-1,j` pairs into a new local variable (also include it in the `private` clause), then use a `reduction` clause to combine the results (although I'm not sure how that works with containers).  Once you're done with your for loop you can output the results, possibly sorting them first.

Trying to parallelize the `j` loop that initializes `a[0]` is probably not worthwhile.  The code needs fixed to get that to work (also mentioned in a comment), and the multiple threads could cause it to run slower if the overhead starting the threads is too much, or if there is cache line contention among threads if multiple threads try to write to nearly adjacent values in memory.  If the sample `s` in your code is typical I'd just run this on one thread.

When you construct your `a` vector, you can include the `-999` initial value in the constructor if the contained vector:

```
vector<vi> a(slen + 1, vi(slen + k + 1, -999));
```

then the initialization loop right below it would just have to set the value of the first element in each contained vector.

That should do for a start.  Note:  Code samples are suggestions, and have not been compiled or tested.

**EDIT** I've worked thru this, and the results are not what you are hoping for.

Initially I just ran your code (to get my baseline performance numbers).  Using VC2010, maximum optimization, 64 bit compile.

```
cl /nologo /W4 /MD /EHsc /Ox /favor:INTEL64 sequencing.cpp
```

Since I don't have your data files, I randomly generated a `t` of 50,000 [AGCT] characters, `s` of 5,000, and used a `k` of 50.  This took **135 seconds** with no hits output.  When I set `t` to be `s` plus 45,000 random characters, I got a lot of hits with no noticeable impact on the execution time.

I got this working with omp (using `firstprivate` instead of `private` to get the initial value of `a` copied in) and it crashed.  Looking in to that I realized that calls to `alignment` **depend on the result of the previous call**.  So this cannot be executed on multiple cores.

I did rewrite `alignment` to remove all the redundant computations and got a reduction of around 25% in the execution time (to **103 seconds**):

```
void alignment(vector<vi>&a, const string &x, const string y, int k){
    string tx,ty;
    int i,j;
    int ylen=int(a[0].size());
    int asize = int(a.size());
    for(i = 1; i < asize; i++) {
        auto xi = x[i - 1];
        int jend = min(ylen, i + k);
        vi &cura = a[i];
        const vi &preva = a[i-1];
        j = max(1, i - k);
        auto caj = cura[j - 1];
        const auto *yp = &y[j - 1];
        auto *pca = &cura[j];
        auto *ppj = &preva[j - 1];
        for(;j <= jend; j++) {
            caj = *pca = max(*ppj - (xi != *yp), max(ppj[1] - 1, caj - 1));
            ++yp;
            ++pca;
            ++ppj;
        }
    }
}
```

The last thing I did was compile this using VS2015.  This reduced the execution time another 28% to around **74 seconds**.

Similar tweaks and adjustments can be made in `main`, but with no observable effect on performance as a majority of time is spent in `alignment`.

Execution times using a 32 bit binary are similar.

It did occur to me that since `alignment` works with a lot of data, it *might* be possible to run this on two (or more) threads, and overlap the area the threads work with (so that the second thread is only accessing elements of the first thread's results once they are computed, but before the first thread has completed working with the entire array.  However, that would require creating your own thread and some very careful synchronization between the thread to ensure the right data is available in the right place.  I didn't try to make this work.

**EDIT 2** The source for an optimized version of main:

```
int main()
{
//  int k = 50;
//  string s = "AATTAGCTAAGGTGTACGATGTCCCATTGTGTAAGATTAGGAACTCCATTTAGGTTACCTCCGTCTTAAGTGATGGACCGTGGGTAGCTGCGTCCGATGGACTCATGCAGCGCCCGGATACCTGCAGTATTTATTATATAGGTCTGCGCACCAAACGATTTCTTTCGTGGTCGGGATTCCGGGGTCCTCCGCTATTCAGAGAGCTAAATA";
//  string t = "ACAATGCAGCAATCCAGCGCCGGAATTTAAGAATAGGTCAGTTTGTAAGGCACTGTTCCCGTTATTCGTAATGCAGTATTAACGTTAATGCTCGAGACCATATTGGACGTCAGTATGCAGACCTGTGCTAGGGTGGTCTATTTCAAGATCACCGAGCTAGGCGCGTGAGCTAACAGGCCGTAATGGTGGCGCCCGCTCCCATAATCACTTCACGAAGCATTAGGTAGACTACCATTTAGGAAGCCCTCTCGCCCGCGTACTGGTTACAGCCCACTACAATGGATACTCCTTACTTCGGTGCAGGCAAGACTTCTACAAAGAAGCGTCCAAGAAGTTGTCGTAGCTCGTTCTTACCCCACCTGTATAAAATTGATCCAGTCGTACATATGACGATGCTGAGCCTCGGACTGGTAAATACAAGTCAAAGGACCAACCCATTACAGTATGAACTACCGGTGG";
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    std::ofstream out("output.txt");
    ifstream someStream( "data.txt" );
    string line;
    getline( someStream, line );    int k = atoi(line.c_str() );
    getline( someStream, line );    string s =line;
    getline( someStream, line );    string t= line;
    int slen=int(s.length()), tlen=int(t.length());

    int i,j;
    vector<vi> a(slen + 1, vi(slen + k + 1, -999));
    a[0][0]=0;
    for(i=1;i<=slen;i++)
        a[i][0]=-i;

    {
        int ej=int(a[0].size());
        for(j=1;j<ej;j++)
            a[0][j] = -j;
    }
    //cout << "init";
    time_t endINIT = time(NULL);
    cout<<"Execution Init Time: "<< (double)(endINIT-start)<<" Seconds"<<std::endl;

    {
        int endi=tlen-slen+k;
        for(i=0;i<=endi;i++)
        {
            alignment(a,s,t.substr(i,slen+k),k);
            int ej=min(slen+k,tlen-i);
            j=max(0,slen-k);
            const auto *aj = &a[slen][j];
            for(;j<=ej;j++,++aj)
            {
                if(*aj>=-k)
                {
                    //cout<<(i+1)<<' '<<j<<endl;
                    out <<(i+1)<<' '<<j<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    time_t end = time(NULL);
    cout<<"Execution Time: "<< (double)(end-start)<<" Seconds"<<std::endl;  
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The code for `alignment` is unchanged from what I listed above.

Comment: If you can test the program to reduce its execution time, the bounty is yours

Comment: @cMinor I'll check that this weekend, I didn't have time to yesterday.

Comment: Nice way to improve `aligment`,however, Do you think there could be a better way to speed up the main function, specially the part where aligment is called? `for(i=0;i<=tlen-slen+k ;i++)
   {
    alignment(a,s,t.substr(i,slen+k),k); 
    for(j=max(0,slen-k);j<=min(slen+k,tlen-i);j++)
    { ....`  I am testing program with this file, Could you please tell How much time it takes to complete in your Computer?https://www.dropbox.com/s/vb9wjho6mp8lvgf/test_k.txt?dl=0  . And finally Does VS 2015 improves the code that much?, why?

Comment: @cMinor VS2010, 94 seconds.  VS2015, 67 seconds.  5318 matches.  Looking at the disassembly of both compilers, it looks like VS2015 does a better job with instruction scheduling, although the instruction choices are slightly different as well.  For the main function, you can assign the `min` that `j` is being compared with to a local variable, and change `a[slen][j]` to be a pointer or iterator like I did in `alignment`.  This won't have much of an effect, though, since most of the time is spent in `alignment`.

Comment: Ok, could you please share all code (main and aligment function) you used so I can award you the bounty ?

Comment: @cMinor Code for main added in another edit to my answer.